# Visual Studio Code cannot find the g++ command of my MinGW-w64

Tags: g++, mingw

Visual Studio Code cannot find the g++ command of my MinGW(btw, intelliSense has no problem because I have set c_cpp_propertites.json correctly). Any idea? Thanks in advance, the following is the output:

Executing task: g++ -g helloworld.cpp

g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue and I believe I've narrowed it down to being due to "g++" being your command. Check your task config file and note what you have set for "command".

"command" is what the task is going to try and run along with whatever arguments you have stipulated which in your case I assume is "-g" and "helloworld.cpp".

Now, what I'm having trouble determining is why it isn't finding g++ as if I try to compile a source file via a command prompt I have no issue and it compiles successfully.

Looking through the documentation for VS code I did find a way to reference your environment variables in the task config: {env:Path} will serve as prefix for my User environment variable "Path" which has a reference to c:\Mingw\lib\bin (note this is an accurate path, simply an example). I think we're pretty close to getting it to work it's just a matter of pathing to g++. My next attempt I think I will simply change "command" to reference an absolute path to g++.

Comment: Confirmed that putting "command" : "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe" removes the g++.exe not found error. Now, it simply returns "1".

Comment: The best advise I could give is install the Cmake Tools plugin within Visual Studio Code.  Next, follow the documentation here to get the build going: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/getting_started.html It really works well and bypasses a number of challenges.

Answer (score 16):

What happened to me was that VSC didn't automatically source my `PATH`. After I added g++, closed and reopened it, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1** - Copy your path of bin file of your mingw compiler (eg. C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin)

**Step 2** - Go to properties by right clicking 'This PC' button.

**Step 3** - [image: Click on the 'Advanced System Settings' as shown in the image.]

**Step 4** - [image: Click on the 'Environment Variables' as shown in the image.]

**Step 5** - [image: Select 'Path' and Click on the 'Edit' button as shown in the image.]

**Step 6** - [image: Paste the path and Click on the 'OK' button as shown in the image.]

If this not work, try this again from beginning.

Comment: You need to restart VScode after setting this up. And some languages may add ";" at the end, when you copy path, make sure it is deleted. Because that could be your source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same problem. Adding the \mingw\bin folder to my PATH variable didn't help. Running g++ in a cmd or PS window worked without a problem so it seems like VSCode is having problems reading or resolving the PATH variable.

To bypass this problem I've included the complete path to g++.exe in the command property of my task. After saving the task, VSCode was able to build my .cpp file.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build g++",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": ["-g", "-o", "${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "${fileBasename}"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The temporary solution for this problem is as follows :---

1. Open VsCode in **Run as administrator** .
2. And set your tasks.json as follows. For ex :-- If your file name is **main.cpp**

[image: Tasks.json]

*It will build the file without error.*

Comment: Running in administrator mode does not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Great! Adding a picture of a JSON instead of copying itself here, how convenient.

Answer (score 2):

1. Search **Path** in windows search box

[image]

2. click on **Environment Variables**

[image]

3. Click on **Path** and hit **Edit**

[image]

4. Go to **C: Drive** and look for **MinGW** folder

[image]

5. then go to **bin** folder and copy the path

[image]

6. Create a **New** variable and paste the path and **move it to the top**

[image]

after that hit ok and restart your terminal/vs code to make it work again.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this issue by adding the path to the bin of mingw-w64 to the windows path by typing setx path into the windows command prompt.
    setx path "%path%;PATHTOBIN"
It would likely return that the PATH has been truncated to 1024 bits, in which case I edited the path variable directly in the register:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Answer (score 1):

Open your tasks.json and launch.json. Make sure that the "preLaunchTask" in launch.json is set to the same string value as the "label" of one the object in the tasks array in the tasks.json file.

[launch.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtXnG.png)

[tasks.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3NI9.png)

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to make sure you have added the

> C:\MinGW\bin
> in the environment variable if you using windows environment

Answer (score 1):

Well, I also faced this problem and I tried every single method but it didn't work properly. But then I did this and it worked.

In Environmental variables under `SYSTEM VARIBALES` create a `VARIABLE` named `CLASSPATH` and `VARIABLE VALUE` as `<path to MinGW>` by clicking `NEW` in `SYSTEM VARIABLES`

[image: The following window will pop up and enter the required inputs]

[image: After the entering it your system variables should look like this]

Answer (score 0):

'$' I had similar problem with vsc.
For me worked out:
1) Making(Remaking) system variable path to `C:\MinGW\bin`.
2) in `c_cpp_properties.json` adding:

```
"browse": {"path": ["${workspaceFolder}","C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\8.2.0\\include\\c++"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the system environment variable ==> Environment variable.. ==>system variable ==>Click Path ( or Select Path + edit) ==> New paste C:\MinGW\bin ==> Ok

Answer (score 0):

After installing MinGW, restart VS Code. The program will definitely execute.

Comment: Please check other answers before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

add the compiler path in the file c_cpp_properties.json as the following

"compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",

it was working for me(add the path with respect to yout g++ exe from your mingw directory) ..

Answer (score -1):

For me, closing and reopening VS Code without changing anything solved my problems.

Comment: Honestly this just worked for me too. lol

Answer (score -1):

Follow instructions given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_hello-world) for the C/C++ programming With VS code

After that if you still get this error that is after instaling MinGW.
Just close the VS code, and open it again.
Everything will fine.