# Visual Studio Code cannot find the g++.exe (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I am setting up the vs code on my windows pc by following this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

I checked the path is correct by calling g++ from other folder.

But I keep getting this error on vs code:

```
Cannot find "C:\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe".
```

tried to run `g++ helloworld.cpp` using command prompt from the folder where `helloworld.cpp` is located does not give error nor output.

Can anyone show me where I did miss something?

EDIT:

The code is actually compiled already.
It produces a.exe and it runs well.
The problem is I need it to be integrated into vs code.
I guess it is similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718765/visual-studio-code-cannot-find-the-g-command-of-my-mingw-w64) but I am not sure.

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

**tasks.json** corrected

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-o",
            "helloworld",
            "helloworld.cpp"
        ],

        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

**tasks.json**

```
    {
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "helloworld",
            "helloworld.cpp"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

**settings.json**

```
{
"[cpp]": {},
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

}

**launch.json**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path is correct? Usually if it says it can't find the file, it's because the file isn't there.

When I install MinGW-W64 it goes to C:(...)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32 . So I suppose your path is wrong as the message says (unless you changed it manually): it should not be in mingw64\bin, but in mingw32\bin.

Comment: I check the path in windows is correct. 
yes, I need to correct the path in json files.

after correcting it, the error code is now 1. before it was 2.

error:
g++.exe: error: f:XXXYYYYcpphelloworld.cpp: No such file or directory
it seems it does not recognise the / characters

Answer (score 0):

In `tasks.json` you have

```
"tasks": [
    {
        ...
        "command": "g++",
        ...
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/"
        },
        ...
```

But you should use your current working directory

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

Comment: I think I found my mistakes.
I have already updated the tasks.json above.

Answer (score 0):

does it work?
I think your tasks.json should be:

```
    {
        // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
        // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "g++.exe build active file",
                "command": "g++",
                "args": [
                    "-g",
                    "helloworld.cpp",
                    "-o",
                    "helloworld"
                ],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The key part is adding the correct cwd option. In this configuration "helloworld" should be right under your workspaceFolder. If that is not the case update the path for helloworld.cpp accordingly.