# My simple code isn't working and it gives me an error

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++, I just started learning and I watch tutorials on youtube. Even though I did everything right, I download compile (g++) etc.. My simple code is not working:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was include
d, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ g++ number1.cpp
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code cannot find the g++ command of my MinGW-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718765/visual-studio-code-cannot-find-the-g-command-of-my-mingw-w64)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1329

Comment: You have not install gcc on your system properly (or), you must add g++ to you system [`path`](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) list to work on cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know c++ never have i coded in it.
But by seeing into your error it seems your g++ compiler is not installed properly. Or if it is installed properly then you forgot to add it into your windows environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly because you might have not added the PATH to your bin folder (MinGW) in Environment Variable.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529400/14002303

You can check the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have installed before `Mingw` , so 99% the problem, is this:

add the PATH to your bin folder in Environment Variable.

**1. open folder** [image: folder windows]

**2. click `this pc`** (folder) [image: this pc on folder g++]
**3. Click `mingw` folder**[image: MinGW]
**4. click `Bin` folder** [image: bin folder]
**5. now to copy the path from the top** [image: C:\MinGW\bin]

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

**6. go another time to `MY PC` folder**

[image: my app folder]

**7. now click in the FREE SPACE with your right-click-mouse** [image: free space on folder app windows right click]

#### what is mean `right-click`?

ok. [image: right click mouse]

**8. click `properties`**

[image: properties on folder app windows]

- now you have a UI like this: [image: preferencies folder app UI]

**9. click `Advanced system settings`**

[image: Advanced system settings, on folder app windows]

**10. click on `Environment variable`**

[image: Environment variable]

- now the UI is like this:

[image: Environment variable UI]

**11. click on `Path`, the Click `Edit...`**

[image: GCC BUG PATH edit Solution on enviroment variable]

- now the UI is like this:
  [image: ui edit enviroment variable on windows folder]

**12. now click `NEW` on the right of the UI of this windows.**

[image: new button png windows]

- now you have 1 more line in the right of this UI :) where you can put your text

[image: what happen if you click new in the edit envirroment variable UI]

**13. NOW paste the `bin directory` in the text-input UI widget**

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

[image: PASTE THE BIN DIRECTORY]

**14. now click `OK` in the bottom in every opened windows**
**15. now check if g++ is setup correctly**
**a. first, open terminal **
**b. write `g++ --version`**

```
g++ --version
```

- if is returning something, this is amazing! , no problems in the future :)

[image: g++ version in ther terminal png]

### need more details on **how to setup g++**? :

[here a video tutorial on this i found for you](https://youtu.be/jvg4VtYEhKU?t=113)

##### not correct?

try use instead `g++` dont use `gcc`

### if you dont know how to execute,

very simple way is *(since you have installed this compiler)* :

- download a extension for vscode, for example `code runner`
  [image: code runner extension vscode]

now you can click in the top-right the green ▶ triangle button. or `CTRL + ALT + N`

code runner write for you the terminal code [image: gcc code runner code terminal]

**OR**

click `CTRL + ALT + B` (but this only create `.exe` file, then you need to open the .exe file)

## **OR MANUALLY**

1. you need first go to your folder using: `cd` [image: cd terminal]
2. you need now the name of folder (where the code `.cpp` is inside)
   [image: name of folder you want]
3. click on terminal, and type the name of the folder

> example: `cd YourFolderName` [image: code for open a folder]

###### trick:

click `TAB` for searching the folder in the fast way :) [image: gif tab trick on terminal]

---

4. **now write `g++`**

(and using the trick of TAB, write name of program c++)

write name of program `.cpp`

5. now you have a `.exe` file created for you
6. just put the name of `.exe`

> without `g++`

something like this:

```
g++ NameOfCppFile.cpp
```

###### usually the name of `.exe file` is `a.exe`

if you want your .exe file having a **custom name**

just put `-o nameOfExeYouWant`

so something like this

```
g++ NameOfCppFile.cpp -o NameOfFile
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem . I just wrote a print program in cpp just to check if everything's okay and working well or not and it was not running . I checked all the paths of mingw bin folders and all , also tried to find solutions to fix the problem and all of them were saying to uninstall mingw . Uninstalling mingw and again installing it and setting it up is a hectic job to me atleast...then I checked other folders where I did C programs and they were running well . So there was no problem with mingw . Then I realised my new folder of C++ programs , I named it c++[DSA] and it was not working just because I used square brackets . Then I renamed it to c++-dsa and it's working now .

Comment: You should just say that you renamed the folder to not include special symbols, the other part of your answer won't help future readers. (But even then, having bad symbols in path would give you a different error, not the one OP had.)